# Run another Python script from current Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have following code:

```
import os
import sys
from random import randint

code = """import os
import sys
from random import randint
from main import code

name = str(randint(0, sys.maxsize))
f = open(name + '.py', 'w+')
f.write(code)
os.system('/usr/local/bin/python3.6 ' + name + '.py')
"""


name = str(randint(0, sys.maxsize))
f = open(name + '.py', 'w+')
f.write(code)
os.system('/usr/local/bin/python3.6 ' + name + '.py')
```

he should create a script with a random name, and execute the. Script created, but he don't execute.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the files? Is there code in them? Because you're not closing/flushing the file

Comment: Thank you. All I had to do was close the file.

Answer (score 3):

`exec(open(‘script.py’).read())` should work. Note that the code will be executed in the current environment (current working directory etc)

Another way is of course running a command as if in a shell. One module that can simulate the full power of a shell is the package [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), where you would be able to take care of `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` as well.

Comment: He still don't run